# Getting the next value in a Queue

Tags: c#, foreach, queue

I have problem today with a queue variable that i am try'n to read in and get the next object inside the queue. I am using a foreach loop that goes through all of the objects inside the queue. But i also want to find out a value of the next object and that is where i am stuck. This is the code that i have completed thus far.

```
private static void outResult(Queue<OrderClass> orderQueue)
    {
        int week = 0;
        int orderCount = 0;
        bool last = false;

        foreach(OrderClass n in orderQueue)
        {
            week = n.DesiredWeek;

            if(week != n.NextWeek)//This is what i want to do
            {
                last = true;
            }
            if(last)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shipping Report for Week {0}", week);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Number of Orders: {0}");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Products shipped: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Cabin:  ");
                Console.WriteLine("LarghFort:  ");
                Console.WriteLine("Ranch:  ");
                Console.WriteLine("Shed:  ");
                Console.WriteLine("SmallHouse:  ");
                Console.WriteLine("Tower:  ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                last = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try `var next  = orderQueue.Pop();`

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like inside the for loop, you want to look at the next value in the queue without removing it.  If that's correct, what you want to use is

```
var next = orderQueue.Peek();
if(week != next.DesiredWeek){
    // do stuff
}
```

**Edit:** My original example was incomplete for your use case.  You'd need to modify how you are iterating as well since the foreach iteration doesn't actually pop elements. See below for a more complete example.

```
var queue = new Queue<int>();
queue.Enqueue(1);
queue.Enqueue(2);
while(queue.Count > 0 )
{
    var val = queue.Dequeue();
    Console.WriteLine("Current: {0}", val);

    if(queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var next = queue.Peek();
        Console.WriteLine("Next: {0}", next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `Queue<T>` is the right structure for the operation you are doing. Seems more like a case for `List<T>` since you are not taking any elements out of the `Queue`.

That being said here are 2 ways to do what you are looking for with a `Queue`.

1. The 'Destructive' way is the way a `Queue` is supposed to be used, you `Dequeue()` the items as you go along. To achieve what you are looking for, after you `Dequeue()` you `Peek()` ahead. Be aware that both functions throw an exception if there is nothing left in the `Queue`. There are multiple ways you can skin this cat. Either you get the `Count` after each iteration in a `while()` loop or like I have shown below just once with a `for` loop. I chose the later for this specific case since you are peeking ahead, too, normally I would use the `while` loop.
2. If you are stuck with a `Queue` but this is just an intermediate function you are calling that must leave the queue untouched and must not `Dequeue()` items, I have added a non-destructive version that just uses enumerators. Note the use of `IEnumerable` in the signature. This will make it work with other Collections that implement this interface as well and is not just restricted to a `Queue` since you are not using `Queue` functionality.

And here is the code example, it prints something out on the console for each iteration but you can see where you would put your code for the 'last' iteration cases.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Queue<OrderClass> orderQueue = new Queue<OrderClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            orderQueue.Enqueue(new OrderClass() { DesiredWeek = (i / 3) });
        }

        outResultNonDestructive(orderQueue);
        outResultDestructive(orderQueue);

    }

    public class OrderClass
    {
        public int DesiredWeek { get; set; }
    }

    private static void outResultDestructive(Queue<OrderClass> orderQueue)
    {
        bool last = false;

        int lengthOfQInTheBeginning = orderQueue.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfQInTheBeginning; i++)
        {
            var current = orderQueue.Dequeue();
            if(i >= lengthOfQInTheBeginning - 1)
            {
                last = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var next = orderQueue.Peek();
                if(current.DesiredWeek != next.DesiredWeek)
                {
                    last = true;
                }
            }
            if (last)
            {
                //Do work...
                Console.WriteLine(current.DesiredWeek.ToString() + " - Last? " + last.ToString());
                last = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(current.DesiredWeek.ToString() + " - Last? " + last.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void outResultNonDestructive(IEnumerable<OrderClass> orderQueue)
    {
        bool last = false;

        IEnumerator<OrderClass> currentEnumerator = orderQueue.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<OrderClass> nextEnumerator = orderQueue.GetEnumerator();

        if(!nextEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            //No elements
        }

        while(currentEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            OrderClass next = null;
            if(nextEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                next = nextEnumerator.Current;
            }
            var current = currentEnumerator.Current;
            if(next == null || current.DesiredWeek != next.DesiredWeek)
            {
                last = true;
            }
            if (last)
            {
                //Do work...
                Console.WriteLine(current.DesiredWeek.ToString() + " - Last? " + last.ToString());
                last = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(current.DesiredWeek.ToString() + " - Last? " + last.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Be aware that neither of the functions are thread safe!